# CSS transform and backface issue

Tags: css

Been stuck on this css issue for a while, have tried looking for answers but come to 2 conclusions. Either a css3 browser glitch or somewhere down the line i have written some wrong code.

Am currently following this tutorial with some variations: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

What I am trying to do is create a menu that appears empty at first and has a flip transform when hovered over with full menu items which then appear. front face and back face are both wrapped in a container. Only thing that you wont be able to see underneath is that there is a button i nested in front face and also back face has a ul in it. I thought they probably wearn't necessary to include.

Below is the css i have currently written up. Would much appreciate if anybody could just help clear this up that i have either written some wrong code here, or there is an issue with my browser. Using chrome and after checking have the latest version. Version 38.0.2125.122. Am still quite new to coding, just finished codecademy and codeschool html/css courses, so would much appreciate any pointers. Thanks ! :)

```
.nav-container {
height: 100px;
width: 62.58692629%;
position: fixed;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;
-webkit-z-index: 1;
}
.face {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background: url(logro.png) top no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 200px;
background-color: #fff;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
position: absolute;
backface-visibility: hideen;
transition: all 1.0s linear;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.nav-container:hover .front.face {
transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.face.back {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
display: block;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: #fff;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
background: url(logro.png);
background-size: 100% 200px;
background-position: 0 -200px;
box-sizing: border-box;
transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

the html below

```
<nav class="nav-container">
        <div class="face front menu">
            <div class="menu-btn">
                <p>menu</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="face back menu">
            <ul class="nav-inner">
                <li><p>Item 1</p></li>
                <li><p>Item 2</p></li>
                <li><p>Item 3</p></li>
                <li><p>Item 4</p></li>
                <li><p>Item 5</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
    </nav>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, in your tutorial, the transition is run on a div wrapping the front and back face, when you've put the transition only on your front face.

When correcting this, everything seems to work properly:

```css
.nav-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 62.58692629%;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.face {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(logro.png) top no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hideen;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.nav-container:hover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.face.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background: url(logro.png);
  background-size: 100% 200px;
  background-position: 0 -200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-container">
  <div class="face front menu">
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <p>menu</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="face back menu">
    <ul class="nav-inner">
      <li>
        <p>Item 1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Item 2</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Item 3</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Item 4</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Item 5</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**PS:** When you want to animate several elements as if they were a single object, I'd say the best solution is almost always wrapping all the elements in a container and animate this container instead.

Comment: Hi Antoine, Just tried out what you've mentioned above and it works like a charm.

Most of all thanks for the P.S. as I'll be sure to keep an eye out from making the same mistake again.

Thanks again, much appreciated! :)

Comment: If my answer suits you, then please remember to mark it as the solution to your question

Comment: My bad, my first post and I forgot, thanks for reminding me though, I will make it a habit to remember it from now on :)